# How to properly test for class inheritance in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, class

In ActionScript 3, you can figure out whether object O is of class C or of a class that extends or implements class C (directly or indirectly) using...

```
if (O is C) {
    ...
}
```

What I want to do is to test whether class CC extends or implements class C (directly or indirectly), without having to instantiate an object.

In Java, you would use...

```
if (C.isAssignableFrom (CC)) {
    ...
}
```

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)

How about ActionScript 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call describeType() on CC directly. You do not have to instantiate the object.

```
var typeXML:XML = describeType(CC);
if(typeXML.factory.extendsClass.(@type=="C").length() > 0)
{
...
```

It's not as clean as I'd like but I can't find anything better.

(via Amarghosh: [http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()][1] )

Comment: Great, thanks. Coming from the rich Java 6 API, I find myself having to reinvent the wheel all the time with Flash/Flex, grrr ;-).

Comment: This is good but relatively slow. If you're just doing this once in a while, you're fine. Otherwise, consider `isPrototypeOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think , you will have to manually parse through the XML object returned by `flash.utils.describeType`

Comment: There is not a way to determine the type simply by looking at the class (except by using `flash.utils.describeType`). You can only do this by instantiating the object first.

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()

Comment: *parentheses are part of the link

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you use [as3commons-reflect](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/) package (which is very, very useful, by the way), you can call:

```
ClassUtils.getImplementedInterfaces(CC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth including the Spicelib [reflection](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.3/manual/reflection.php) library as another alternative. Specifically [ClassInfo.isType](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.4/api/spicelib/org/spicefactory/lib/reflect/ClassInfo.html#isType%28%29).

> Checks whether the class or interface
>   represented by this ClassInfo instance
>   is a subclass or subinterface of the
>   specified class

```
ClassInfo.forClass(A).isType(B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack I just found.
Not sure how solid it is, but it works for me.

```
var child:Child = getChild() as Parent;
if(child != null) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`describeType()` is very slow, computationally speaking. If you need to determine the inheritance chain of uninstantiated classes, consider using `Class.prototype` and `prototype.isPrototypeOf()`. This allows you to check inheritance and equality if all you have are the Classes themselves (as opposed to an object that is an instance of that Class).

If you only have a String representation of the class name (as opposed to the Class itself), then you have to convert that to a proper Class first, using `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName()` assuming you have at least declared the class somewhere in your code. If the class only exists somewhere in a loaded SWF Library, you may have to use something like `ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinitionByName()` or `contextLoader.currentDomain.getDefinitionByName()`.

Here's a working example that accepts either Classes or String class names and checks whether the first one is in the inheritance chain of the second one. The additional argument allows you to decide whether you want to return false if the two classes are identical rather than the first extending the second.

```
/**
 * Determines whether the childClass is in the inheritance chain of the parentClass. Both classes must be declared
 * within the current ApplicationDomain for this to work.
 * 
 * @param   childClass
 * @param   parentClass
 * @param   mustBeChild
 */
public static function inheritsFrom(childClass:*, parentClass:*, mustBeChild:Boolean = false) {
    var child:Class,
        parent:Class;

    if (childClass is Class) {
        child = childClass;
    } else if (childClass is String){
        child = getDefinitionByName(childClass) as Class;
    }

    if (! child) {
        throw new ArgumentError("childClass must be a valid class name or a Class");
    }

    if (parentClass is Class) {
        parent = parentClass;
    } else if (parentClass is String){
        parent = getDefinitionByName(parentClass) as Class;
    }

    if (! parent) {
        throw new ArgumentError("parentClass must be a valid class name or a Class");
    }

    if (parent.prototype.isPrototypeOf(child.prototype)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (mustBeChild) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (parent.prototype === child.prototype) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```