# AS3: How to implement instanceOf with classes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, apache-flex, casting

I want to implement this method

```
function isInstance(a:Class, b:Class):Boolean;
```

This is how AS3 work with Classes. *Note that [MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) extends Sprite.*

```
trace(MovieClip is Sprite); // false
trace(Sprite is MovieClip); // false
trace(Sprite is Sprite); // false
trace(Sprite is Object); // true
```

I been trying the next code but it is not working:

```
/**
* return if instance of class 'a' can be cast to instant of class 'b'
*/
private function isInstance(a:Class, b:Class):Boolean{
    var superclass:Class = a;
    do {
        if (superclass == b) {
            return true;
        }
        superclass = getSuperClass(a);
    } while (superclass != null);

    return false;
}

private function getSuperClass(claz:Class):Class{
    var qualifiedSuperclassName:String = getQualifiedSuperclassName(claz);
    var returnValue:Class = getDefinitionByName(qualifiedSuperclassName) as Class;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693572/how-to-properly-test-for-class-inheritance-in-actionscript-3

Comment: @MichaelBrewer-Davis describeType is very expensive, my solution is better

Answer (score 0):

Found solution in this [site](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1440#more-1440).

It is simple as that:

```
private function isSubclassOfSkyboy(a:Class, b:Class): Boolean
{
    if (int(!a) | int(!b)) return false;
    return (a == b || a.prototype instanceof b);
}
```

There is a use here of **instanceof** that been deprecated from as3. As I understood he cannot be replaced with **is** in this case, but correct me if I am wrong. Any way read the article before commenting.

Comment: Prototypes are generally not used in ActionScript 3.  I think what you want is the 'is' operator.  Also read here about why to avoid the instanceOf operator in ActionScript: http://www.opencoder.co.uk/2011/04/instanceof-is-bad-in-actionscript/ .

Comment: @Reboog711 Read the reference article, they knows that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ActionScript docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8a.html)

> The is operator should be used instead of the instanceof operator for
>   manual type checking, because the expression x instanceof y merely
>   checks the prototype chain of x for the existence of y (and in
>   ActionScript 3.0, the prototype chain does not provide a complete
>   picture of the inheritance hierarchy).

And their samples:

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
trace(mySprite is Sprite); // true 
trace(mySprite is DisplayObject);// true 
trace(mySprite is IEventDispatcher); // true
```

It sounds to me like you're trying to do this the hard way.

Comment: You are comparing object with class, it's not what I am looking for. See my question edit, it is clearly seen what is the problem.

Comment: You're right; this compares an object instance with a class type.  That is exactly what instanceOf does, right?  What is the use case for comparing two objects?

Comment: I do not want to compare two objects but two classes. This is the method that I want to implement: function isInstance(a:Class, b:Class):Boolean

Comment: My typo, sorry.  What is the use case for comparing two classes?  Are you writing some type of code introspection tool?

Comment: I am writing my own implementation for events mechanism and I want to allow classes to register for events even before they created. It's very useful for factory.